# Howcome I can't use a BorderLayout with my panel?

Tags: jpanel

I am making a program in which there is one frame, which contains a GridLayout g = (2,2), meaning essentially a square divided into four parts. In each part i have added a panel and named them accordingly (tl = top left, tr = to pright, bl = bottom left, br = bottom right) and now I want to add panels into those panels. I want to set the layout of Panel tl to a BorderLayout, and then add a another panel - called tl1 - into tl. Here is my code, but for some reason it won't let me do this. I'm a beginner in java so i'm not really sure exactly how everything works so this might be a stupid question, but as i looked at the syntax for border layout it said that it was written like (component, BORDER.LAYOUT North) or something. Is JPanel not a component and is that why this isn't working?

```
public class BattleShipGrid {
JFrame frame  = new JFrame("Battleship");
//JPanel tl = new JPanel();
JPanel tl = new JPanel();
JPanel tl1 = new JPanel();
JPanel tr = new JPanel();
JPanel bl = new JPanel();
JPanel br = new JPanel();

JButton  b1 = new JButton();

GridLayout g = new GridLayout(2,2,2,2);
GridLayout gtl = new GridLayout(11,11,2,2);

JButton[][] tlba;

public BattleShipGrid(){
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(800,800);
frame.setBackground(Color.RED);
frame.setLayout(g);
frame.add(tl);tl.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
tl.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(tr);//tr.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
frame.add(bl);//bl.setBackground(Color.GREEN); 
frame.add(br);//br.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
/*GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.insets = new Insets(15,15,0,0);
tl.setLayout(gtl);
gbc.gridx = 3;
gbc.gridy = 3;
tl1.add(b1); 
*/
//ADD A TOOLBAR SO THAT THE USER CAN MAKE A NEW GAME OR ACCESS OTHER OPTIONS
tl1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
tl.add(tl1, BorderLayout); 

tl1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
```

Answer (score 0):

Im almost sure you don't need the answer anymore but you need to edit your line "tl.add(tl1, BorderLayout);" to either one of these

```
tl.add(tl1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
tl.add(tl1, BorderLayout.EAST);
tl.add(tl1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
tl.add(tl1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
tl.add(tl1, BorderLayout.WEST);
```